# How to add additional field to the Admin side Order checkout form Shipping address in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

I want to add an additional field to the Create New Address filed list in the admin create order section. I could not find the template corresponding to that. How can I overwrite and what is that template

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses one template for billing and shipping address: `Magento_Sales::order/create/form/address.phtml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Address" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/form/address.phtml" name="shipping_address">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="customerAddressFormatter" xsi:type="object">Magento\Sales\ViewModel\Customer\AddressFormatter</argument>
                    <argument name="customerAddressCollection" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection</argument>
                    <argument name="customerAddressCollectionAttributeFilter" xsi:type="object">Magento\Sales\ViewModel\Customer\Address\AddressAttributeFilter</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you want to change template you need modify it in few layouts:

- `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml`
- `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_data.xml`
- `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_shipping_address.xml`

Or customize in your theme like

`app/design/adminhtml/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Sales/templates/order/create/form/address.phtml`

**Form [Added]**

You can see form logic in
`\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Address::_prepareForm`

Magento uses all Customer Address attributes assigned to `adminhtml_customer_address` form.

You can manage those attributes with admin area [Customer Address Attributes](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/attributes-customer-address.html). Create you own attribute and select **Customer Account Address** in **Forms to Use**

Comment: Thank you. I checked the address.phtml and the part which I need to modify is represented by using the following

<?= $block->getForm()->toHtml() ?>

do you know where is it?  I want add another field to it

Comment: Added more info into Answer